# Comparing $\left\| A_n^{-1/2} B_n A_n^{-1/2}-I_k\right\|\xrightarrow{\ \ \mathbb P\ \ } 0$ and $\|B_n - A_n\|\xrightarrow{\ \ \mathbb P\ \ } 0$

Tags: probability, random-matrices

Let $(A_n)$ and $(B_n)$ be two sequences of random $k \times k$ positive definite matrices. Let $I_k$ be the identity matrix of size $k$, and $\left\|M\right\|=\sqrt{\mathrm{trace}(M^T M)}$ for any $M \in \mathbb R^{k \times k}$. I need to compare the two following conditions:

1. $\left\|A_n^{-1/2} B_n A_n^{-1/2} - I_k\right\| \xrightarrow{\ \ \mathbb P\ \ } 0$
2. $\left\|B_n - A_n\right\| \xrightarrow{\ \ \mathbb P\ \ } 0$

i.e.

1. $\mathbb P\!\left(\left\|A_n^{-1/2} B_n A_n^{-1/2} - I_k\right\| > \varepsilon\right) \to 0$ for every $\varepsilon >0$
2. $\mathbb P\!\left(\left\|B_n - A_n\right\| > \varepsilon\right) \to 0$ for every $\varepsilon >0$

What I am told is that the two conditions are different, “because $\left\|A_n\right\| \to 0$ in most applications” (I’m omitting the context because I’m fairly sure it isn’t relevant). But I fail to see if any of the two is stronger than the other, and what is the exact role of $\left\|A_n\right\|$ tending to $0$.

All I have done is noticing that, by the sub-multiplicativity of $\|\cdot\|$,

- $\left\|A_n^{-1/2} B_n A_n^{-1/2} - I_k\right\| = \left\|A_n^{-1/2} (B_n - A_n) A_n^{-1/2}\right\| \leq \left\|A_n^{-1/2}\right\|^2 \left\|B_n - A_n\right\|$

  $\implies \mathbb P\!\left(\left\|A_n^{-1/2} B_n A_n^{-1/2} - I_k\right\| > \varepsilon \right) \leq \mathbb P\!\left(\left\|A_n^{-1/2}\right\|^2 \left\|B_n - A_n\right\| > \varepsilon\right)$
- $\left\|B_n - A_n\right\| = \left\|A_n^{1/2} (A_n^{-1/2} B_n A_n^{-1/2} - I_k) A_n^{1/2}\right\| \leq \left\|A_n^{1/2}\right\|^2 \left\|A_n^{-1/2} B_n A_n^{-1/2} - I_k\right\|$

  $\implies \mathbb P\!\left(\left\|B_n - A_n\right\| > \varepsilon\right) \leq \mathbb P\!\left(\left\|A_n^{1/2}\right\|^2 \left\|A_n^{-1/2} B_n A_n^{-1/2} - I_k\right\| > \varepsilon\right)$
- $\left\|A_n^{-1/2}\right\|^2 \geq \left\| \left( A_n^{-1/2} \right)^2 \right\| = \left\|A_n^{-1}\right\| \geq \left\|A_n\right\|^{-1}$
- $\left\|A_n^{1/2}\right\|^2 \geq \left\| \left( A_n^{1/2} \right)^2 \right\| = \left\|A_n\right\|$

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remark that $\Vert A_n \Vert \overset{ \mathbb P}{ \to} 0 \iff A_n \overset{ \mathbb P}{ \to} 0 $ (the null matrix). So, if $\Vert A_n \Vert \overset{ \mathbb P}{ \to} 0 $, then 1. implies 2. , using that
$$ \Vert B_n -  A_n \Vert \leq \Vert A_n^{1/2} \Vert^2 \Vert A_n^{-1/2} B_n A_n^{-1/2} - I \Vert $$
However, if $\Vert A_n \Vert \overset{ \mathbb P}{ \to} 0 $ then
$$ \Vert B_n -  A_n \Vert \leq \Vert B_n \Vert + \Vert A_n \Vert    $$
tends to zero in probability for any $B_n$ such that $\Vert B_n \Vert \overset{ \mathbb P}{ \to} 0$. Thus, we can easily build a counter-example to show that 2. does not imply 1. in this case.

Conversely,
$$  \Vert A_n^{-1/2} \Vert^2 \Vert A_n^{-1/2} B_n A_n^{-1/2} - I \Vert  \leq \Vert B_n -  A_n \Vert $$
so if $\Vert A_n^{-1} \Vert$ is bounded in probability, then so is $\Vert A_n^{-1/2} \Vert$ and 2. implies 1.

Comment: May I ask you to include a proof of these statements in your answer?

Comment: (Even of the one that I supposedly showed already, because I don’t think I did…)

Comment: Is this more helpful?

Comment: You’re assuming that $\| A_n \| \xrightarrow{\ \ \mathbb P\ \ } 0$ implies $\| A_n^{1/2} \| \xrightarrow{\ \ \mathbb P\ \ } 0$, right? Unfortunately I’m failing to seeing why that should be the case

Comment: that's because $\Vert A_n \Vert \overset{ \mathbb P}{ \to} 0 \iff A_n \overset{ \mathbb P}{ \to} 0 \iff A_n^{1/2} \overset{ \mathbb P}{ \to} 0 $

Comment: If $A_n$ is symmetric (which I assume is the case in your problem), the frobenius norm (the one you use) is the Eucliden norm of the vector of eigenvalues of $A_n$. So, the Frobenius norm of $A_n^{1/2}$ is the sum of the eigenvalues of $A_n$ (since they are non-negative).